# gradle sync stuck at importing web configuration model data (Intellij IDEA UE / macOS)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Stuck on `Importing web configuration model data` on doing a gradle `Reload All Projects`.

Tried:

- reboot
- invalidating cache
- bumping up the heap size (vmoptions)

Noticed:

- network activity is minimal (~30KB/s)

Please help! Using IDEA as the build tool. Gradle 7.3.3 in the project. IDEA version is 2023.2.2 UE. JDK 11 corretto.

---

Also: on interrupting, the ProcessCancelledException is thrown from `com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProcessCancelledException`. I tried disabling the OpenAPI plugin and retrying, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known issue described in

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-306665/Gradle-import-gets-stuck-on-importing-web-configuration-model-data

Please upvote it and provide logs and the CPU snapshots.

Comment: Like suggested in a comment there, I've switched to the CE version for now, which works well without the issue. I can't provide logs without a significant amount of work to remove sensitive data, but could consistently observe that the issue has to do with `com.intellij.openapi`